# JAX-B: Missing XML attributes on child elements

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, moxy

**Edit:** I originally left out what may be an important detail from my question -- My service methods that return Java objects to be marshaled return an interface type (`Foo`) rather than the class implementation type (`FooImpl`).

I have a simple Java class with JAX-B annotations for several elements and attributes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
public class FooImpl {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId() {
            return Id;
    }

    public void setId(final String id) {
            this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Edit:  The FooImpl class has an interface named `Foo`:

```
public interface Foo {
    public String getName();
    public void setName(final String name);

    public String getId();
    public void setId(final String id);
}
```

When I have a service method that returns a `Foo`, I get what I expect:

```
<foo id="abc123">
  <name>bar</name>
</foo>
```

But I also have another class that contains a `List<Foo>` and when it is marshalled, the XML elements for `foo` **do not contain their `id` attribute**!!

```
<foos>
    <foo>
      <name>bar1</name>
    </foo>
    <foo>
      <name>bar2</name>
    </foo>
</foos>
```

The class that holds the list looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foos")
public class Foos {

    private List<Foo> foos;

    @XmlElement(name = "foo")
    public List<Foo> getFoos() {
        return foos;
    }

    public void setFoos(List<Foo> foos) {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

}
```

I happen to be using MOXy as my JAX-B implementation, but I do not think that matters.

Comment: Are you sure the objects in memory (prior to marshalling) contain non-null values for the `id` attributes?

Comment: Yes.  I can return any one of the `Foo` objects by itself and see the attribute value(s).  But when the same object is part of the `Foos` collection I cannot.  I am testing the web service directly from Eclipse via HTTP4E so I can see the payloads exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Since you have a property whose type is an interface you will need to specify the implementing type on the `@XmlElement` annotation:

```
@XmlElement(name = "foo", type=FooImpl.class)
public List<Foo> getFoos() {
   return foos;
}
```

Below is a complete example:

**Foos**

```
package forum9137171;

import java.util.List;  
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "foos")
public class Foos {

    private List<Foo> foos;

    @XmlElement(name = "foo", type=FooImpl.class)
    public List<Foo> getFoos() {
        return foos;
    }

    public void setFoos(List<Foo> foos) {
        this.foos = foos;
    }

}
```

**Foo**

```
package forum9137171;

public interface Foo {
    public String getName();
    public void setName(final String name);

    public String getId();
    public void setId(final String id);
}
```

**FoomImpl**

```
package forum9137171;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getId() {
            return id;
    }

    public void setId(final String id) {
            this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum9137171;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foos.class);
        System.out.println(jc);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum9137171/input.xml");
        Foos foos = (Foos) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foos, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Input/Output**

```
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext@16a786
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foos>
   <foo id="abc123">
      <name>bar1</name>
   </foo>
   <foo id="def456">
      <name>bar2</name>
   </foo>
</foos>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-interface-fronted-models.html

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  Its is helpful to know that there is nothing wrong with my annotations or expectations.  It must be something in my environment.  I will try to create a reproducible test case.

Comment: In creating a reproducible test case I found a potentially important difference between my code and the scaled down code in the original question.  Please see my edit above.  Foo is an interface which is implemented by the FooImpl class.  I only have JAX-B annotations on FooImpl only howver.  Also note that the service methods that return a `Foo` work...but the one that returns `List<Foo>` does not.

Comment: Your answer worked perfectly...thanks.  I guess it does leave me wondering why JAXB can't figure out the implementation type backing the interface on its own.  Also it makes me wonder why the returning a Single `Foo` ever worked?!